# Error: Multiple destinations cannot be specified

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to configure sending out message to two out put streams like following.

```
@StreamListener(SampleBinding.INPUT1)
@SendTo({SampleBinding.OUTPUT1, SampleBinding.OUTPUT2})
public String handleM(String sampleMessage){
    log.info("Received message="+sampleMessage.toString());
    sampleMessage=sampleMessage.toUpperCase();
    return sampleMessage;
}
```

I followed this [example](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/blob/master/kafka-streams-samples/kafka-streams-branching/src/main/java/kafka/streams/branching/KafkaStreamsBranchingSample.java#L50)

It's giving the following error.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple destinations cannot be specified
>       at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:118)
>       at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerMethodUtils.getOutboundBindingTargetName(StreamListenerMethodUtils.java:146)
>       at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$DefaultStreamListenerSetupMethodOrchestrator.orchestrateStreamListenerSetupMethod(StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
>       at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.doPostProcess(StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:195)
>       at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.lambda$postProcessAfterInitialization$0(StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:167)
>       at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
>       at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.injectAndPostProcessDependencies(StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
>       at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.afterSingletonsInstantiated(StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:105)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:863)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.servle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to send to multiple destinations as you describe from a `StreamListener` method when using regular `MessageChannel` based binders. It is possible to send to multiple topics using the Kafka Streams binder's branching feature which you are referring to in the link provided above. If you want to send to multiple destinations in your application, one option is to use the dynamic destination feature of Spring Cloud Stream. [Here is an example](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/source-samples/dynamic-destination-source) of how dynamic destinations work.

Comment: Thanks @sobychacko understood it properly now.